# Why don't Universal Links in iOS 9 work sometimes?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I implemented the universal links in my app, I followed this article:
[universal links on ios9](http://blog.hokolinks.com/how-to-implement-apple-universal-links-on-ios-9/)

Yesterday everything worked, but today if I open my test app and try to open my main app with universal links, the test app just show me the safari and load my url, but it doesnt offer to open the universal link in my main app. 
I didnt get any errors, so I dont know what should I have to do.

Comment: If you tapped the button at the top right to go to the URL once you were in the main app, it will continue to go to the URL instead of the main app. To get it to open the main app again instead of Safari, tap the OPEN button in your Smart App Banner. Or, delete the apps and try again.

Comment: I tried to delete the app and reinstall, reboot device, but my app always run in safari... I see in the server logs that the apple-app-site-association file was downloaded by the device when i installed it, but not always. So i don't know whats wrong, i will use url schemes instead.

Comment: Hm I would verify everything is still passing using the Search Validation Tool. https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/

Comment: Well, the universal links not passed, its just "Recommended" but the tool found the apple-app-site-association file on the server. I have SSL certificate, but the apple file unsigned.

Comment: The file doesn't need to be signed, but you'll need to get universal links to pass instead of show as recommended.

Comment: but how can i get universal links? could you give me a good tutorial?

Comment: check whether you have implemented Universal Link correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it/35609668#35609668

Answer (score 2):

Quick steps to check whether you have implemented Universal Link correctly.

- Tap and hold on the link that you expect to launch the app. You should see a "Open in [your app name]" in the Context Menu.
- Open Notes app, type the link you expect to open the app. Tap Done. The link will turn yellow and tapping on the link should open your app, and not Safari.
- If the link http://yourDomain.com is not launching the app, try     http://yourDomain.com/yourFolder/
- In Safari, If the Context Menu shows "Open in [your app name]" in safari, but tapping the link opens the link in safari itself instead of launching the app,

  a. Try pulling down on the safari page that opened when the link was clicked like the way you 'pull to refresh'. A banner should appear that can open your app. Tap the banner to open the app, close the app by pressing home button, get back to safari and try launching the app by tapping the link again. This time on, the app should get launched because tapping the banner should have saved the preference to open the link in app.

  b. If the app still don't get launched after the step a., try mailing the link to a webmail such as gmail and open the webmail site in safari and try clicking the link. If this works, you may have been trying to launch the app from the same domain as the link. From what I have seen, launching the app from the same domain mostly fails. Probably safari wont care to check whether the destination url is a universal link, when the link is into the same domain. So try to launch the app from another domain.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I am not able to see "Open in [my app]" option. Is there a reason why I am not able to see that option? Is that a sign that universal links are not properly implemented?